# FaultException thrown from async method with void return type is not returned to client

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.5

```
public async void LogOutUser(string sessionId)
{
   ...
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       throw new FaultException("Session Unauthorized", CustomFaultCode.SessionUnknownError);
   }
}
```

The code above crashes IIS Apppool. However, below code returns FaultException to client:

```
public async Task<List<User>> GetUserList(string sessionId)
{
    ...
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ServiceFaultException("Invalid SessionID", CustomFaultCode.SharedSessionUnknownError);
    }
}
```

}

Both methods are marked with [OperationContract] attribute only. For testing I'm using WCFTestClient.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? 4.5?

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a Task instead from the operation, which will allow WCF a way to know that the operation completed successfully or with errors and pass the fault to the client:

```
public async Task LogOutUser(string sessionId)
```